# Calling Email template in Visual Force page using Iframe

Tags: visualforce, email, iframe, template

I'm new to this sales force platform.I'm facing the problem to call the email template in visual force page using iframe.
my code look like this.

```
<apex:iframe
    id="previewFrame"
    title="HTML Preview" 
    src="https://{!sfdcBaseURL}.content.force.com/email/templaterenderer?id={!MailselectedTemplate.id}&recipient_type_id={!$User.Id}&related_to_id={!regid}&base_href=https://{!sfdcBaseURL}.salesforce.com&preview_frame=previewFrame&render_type=REPLACED_HTML_BODY&setupid=CommunicationTemplatesEmail"  
    frameborder="false"
    height="450"
    width="100%"/>
```

It's working in my Development org but I'm facing the problem in production org. 
I think it conflicts in `sfdcBaseURL`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the sfdcBaseURL, you can use the custom label where you store the production url and then use it in the source.

Or

You can use the **URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost()** function to get the host URL and set that to a variable and use the variable in the source

Comment: You are welcome